# Reward function definition in MRP/MDP, reinforcement learning different notations

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process

I started to self-taught reinforcement learning a few weeks ago. These days I've encountered a problem with the definition of the reward function.

The reward function, defines and quantifies the reward the agent will get, at **(s)** or **(s, a)** or **(s, a, s')** [depends on the reward function we defined in the specific problem]. We usually said the MDP is a 5-element tuple, which is **(, , P, r, gamma)**,where:

- : the state set that contain all *s*, ***s* ∈**
- : the action set that contains all action *a*, ***a*∈**
- ***gamma***: discount factor
- **P**: transition probability, which is **P(s' | s, a)**

However, for the "*r*", "*R*", or "" in the tuple, I found that different textbook defined it a bit differently...

---

*In Sutton & Barto's "*Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction*"* :

- *r* is the reward
- *Rt* or *Rt+1* is the actual reward the agent will get at a certain time step
- [image] is the reward set that contains all possible reward values, which is a subset of real numbers [image]
- *r (s, a)* or *r (s)* is the **expected value of reward** at *(s, a)* or *(s)*

Actually I didn't see the word "5 tuple" in the textbook, they just simply defined a "joint" probability which is *p(s', r | St = s, At = a)*.

---

*In David Silver's lecture on introduction of RL:*

- *Rt* or *Rt+1* is the actual reward the agent will get at a certain time step
- [image] is the **"reward function"**, which is the **expected value of reward** at *(s, a)* or *(s)*

---

*In some other sources (University of Toronto, CSC311 lecture slide)* :

- *Rt* or *Rt+1* is the actual reward the agent will get at a certain time step
- [image] is a distribution of possible rewards at (s, a) (for a stochastic reward process)

[image]
from [chrome-extension://fcejkolobdcfbhhakbhajcflakmnhaff/pages/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.toronto.edu%2F~michael%2Fteaching%2Fcsc311_w23%2Flectures%2Flec12_mz.pdf#pagemode=thumbs]

In addition, from some other answers here in StackExchange website, some people explained "reward function" as it defines the actual reward/reward distribution rather than an expected value of reward the agent will get at (s, a), or (s), or (s, a, s')

---

I understand that in difference sources, the notation maybe a bit different. For a deterministic reward process, the expected value of reward is the actual reward value itself. For a stochastic reward process, the **expected reward** and the actual reward the agent will get from the distribution (or reward possibility distribution) are different concepts.

I was just a bit confused by all these different 'standard' of notation when people define the term 'reward function'.

For the definition of reward function *r (s)*, or *r (s, a)*, or *r (s, a, s')*, sometimes people refers the expected reward function, which defines the **expected reward** (in both deterministic & stochastic). Other times people refers to just the reward function, which defines the actual reward (deterministic)/reward distribution (stochastic)..

I think in the field of RL, these two kinds of definitions of 'reward function' just being used interchangeably.. This question may looks a bit "waste of time", but I just post here for if someone also encounter a similar situation as me..Thanks